# Implementation of the DefaultTerminalConverters in order to instantiate Integer instead of terminal rule in Xtext throws ClassCastException

Tags: dsl, xtext

I want to implement my own DefaultTerminalConverters class in order to insatiate Integer instead of terminal rule VALUE_TERMINAL

VALUE_TERMINAL from my grammar is:

```
terminal VALUE_TERMINAL: 
    ( '0' .. '9' )+ ;
```

code of my own DefaultTerminalConverters is:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.xtext.common.services.DefaultTerminalConverters;
import org.eclipse.xtext.conversion.IValueConverter;
import org.eclipse.xtext.conversion.ValueConverter;
import org.eclipse.xtext.conversion.impl.AbstractLexerBasedConverter;
import org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.INode;

public class MyLangValueConverter extends DefaultTerminalConverters {
    @Inject MyINTValueConverter myINTValueConverter;

    @ValueConverter(rule="VALUE_TERMINAL") 
    public IValueConverter<Integer> VALUE_TERMINAL() {
        return myINTValueConverter;
    }

    private static class MyINTValueConverter extends AbstractLexerBasedConverter<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer toValue(String string, INode node) {
            return new Integer(string);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(Integer value){
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm writing someting in my own DSL I'm always getting error `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` when using VALUE_TERMINAL. What could be the problem ?

Comment: In what line does the exception occur?

Comment: It doesn't occur in this class. When I run new instance of Eclipse with my DSL and write something in this DSL I can see that `toValue()` method is executed correctly when VALUE_TERMINAL rule is instantiated. But in console in this second instance of the eclipse I see that exception, but I dont know where is it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the grammar:

```
terminal VALUE_TERMINAL: 
( '0' .. '9' )+ ;
```

is short for

```
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
...
terminal VALUE_TERMINAL returns ecore::EString: 
( '0' .. '9' )+ ;
```

so you need to specify the returned datatype for the terminal rule explicitly. something like

```
terminal VALUE_TERMINAL returns ecore::EInt:
```

or

```
terminal VALUE_TERMINAL returns ecore::EIntegerObject:
```

Comment: `returns ecore::EIntegerObject` works. Thanks @Christian